# How to edit XML file to change all number by shell script, in which original point divided by 1.3?

Tags: python, linux, bash, perl, shell

Original xml:

```
<dimen name="placeHolderXNot10">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYNot10">35dp</dimen>

<dimen name="placeHolderXFor10">15dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYFor10">35dp</dimen>

<dimen name="rightNot10">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="topNot10">75dp</dimen>
<dimen name="bottomNot10">15dp</dimen>
```

**After dividing the number by 1.3, **

```
<dimen name="placeHolderXNot10">15.38dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYNot10">26.92dp</dimen>

<dimen name="placeHolderXFor10">15.38dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYFor10">26.92dp</dimen>

<dimen name="rightNot10">30.76dp</dimen>
<dimen name="topNot10">57.69dp</dimen>
<dimen name="bottomNot10">11.53dp</dimen>
```

I have more xml file in which i want to change the density pixel.

Comment: It's customary to demonstrate the code you've written thus far, so that we can help with the specific part you are struggling with.  As for an approach, a good start is to use a parsing library in the programming language of your choosing.

Comment: No code posted, that's not nice.

Comment: Gerry, there is no need to more code, it's nice.

Comment: You absolutely should include a [mcve]. Otherwise, it sounds like you're just asking people to do your work for you, which is rude.

Comment: BTW, you currently have 3/5 close votes, so I would seriously consider editing your question to include the code you've written so far and the reason why it's not working.

Comment: Matt, okay i think it was misunderstanding i don't mean to say like that.

Comment: @Vibhanshu Shukla -- if following solution helped which seems from your comments. then please accept the answer by clicking tick mark left to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to `awk` solution :

```
awk -v FS='[^>]>|<'  '/</{x=$3/1.3"dp";gsub($3,x)}1' inputfile

<dimen name="placeHolderXNot10">15.3846dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYNot10">26.9231dp</dimen>

<dimen name="placeHolderXFor10">11.5385dp</dimen>
<dimen name="placeHolderYFor10">26.9231dp</dimen>

<dimen name="rightNot10">30.7692dp</dimen>
<dimen name="topNot10">57.6923dp</dimen>
<dimen name="bottomNot10">11.5385dp</dimen>
```